# How can I update an existing serverless 0.5.x stack with serverless 1.x?

Tags: serverless-framework, aws-serverless

We have several aws stacks that were deployed using serverless 0.5 and now we are trying to move to serverless 1.x.
We have migrated the configuration (serverless.yml) and all, but our problem comes when we try to update the actual stack. 
Serverless 1 uses deployment buckets that the old serverless 0.5 stacks don't have and we can't seem to get those buckets to create. We get the following error:
`Resource ServerlessDeploymentBucket does not exist for stack <stack name>`.
Is there any way around this other than simply deleting all the old stacks?
Some of them have database tables and buckets associated with them and we can't risk loosing the data in them.
Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, so I got around this issue by using the plug-in `serverless-plugin-create-deployment-bucket`. It works well and now I can take over old serverless 0.5 stacks... just need to be able to update lambdas now...